# Proper imports for database mapping in a class

Tags: vb.net, import, mapping, database-connection, inheritance

I am trying to map class properties to a database.  What imports to I need to use in order to make this work?

```
<Table(Name:="ACTN.users_tbl")> _
Public Class users
    <Column(Name:="id")> _
    Public Property id As Integer
    <Column(Name:="username")> _
    Public Property username As String
    <Column(Name:="password")> _
    Public Property password As String
    <Column(Name:="password_old")> _
    Public Property password_old As String
    <Column(Name:="salt")> _
    Public Property salt As String
    <Column(Name:="role_id")> _
    Public Property role As Integer
    <Column(Name:="active")> _
    Public Property active As Boolean
    <Column(Name:="dt_created")> _
    Public Property dt_created As DateTime
    <Column(Name:="dt_updated")> _
    Public Property dt_updated As DateTime
End Class
```

It gives me this error

> 'Table' cannot be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute'.

However adding "imports System.Attribute" before the class, or adding "inherits System.Attribute" to the class does not resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the correct namespace `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx)).

Make sure you have referenced `System.Data.Linq.dll` in your project.

Comment: I tried the System.Data.Ling.Mapping namespace and it didn't work however the second part of your answer is really what I needed.  After referencing System.Data.Linq.dll in my project the namespace did work correctly.